# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}$

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}$? It seems just a Calc II peoblem... But we should apply which rules?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Use partial fractions; note that

$$\frac1{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} = \frac13 \left (\frac1{x^2+1}-\frac1{x^2+4} \right ) $$

Answer (score 0):

Partial fractions:

$$\frac1{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4}\iff$$

$$1=(Ax+B)(x^2+4)+(Cx+D)(x^2+1)$$

Comparing coefficients of corresponding powers of $\;x\;$ in both sides:

$$\begin{align*}I&x^3:&\;\;0=A+C\implies& A=-C\\{}\\
II&x^2:&\;\;0=B+D\implies& B=-D\\{}\\
III&x:&\;\;0=4A+C\implies& C=-4A\\{}\\
IV&x^0:&\;\;1=4B+D\end{align*}$$

And thus we get:

$$\begin{cases}I+III\implies A=C=0\\{}\\
II+IV\implies B=\frac13=-D\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}=\frac13\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}-\frac13\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\frac14dx}{1+\left(\frac x4\right)^2}$$

So you have to arctangents and etc.